# Doctrine - Table without primary keys

Tags: doctrine

I use doctrine.
It's possible to generate entities who based on a database with table (important) without primary key ?
The DB is for Chacal XXI (an application) and 1 or 2 tables have not primary keys, i can't add primary key manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. From https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys :

> Every entity class must have an identifier/primary key. You can select the field that serves as the identifier with the @Id annotation.

Comment: Any chance you could update your answer. The link is 404 now.